# What happens to items when I kill monsters off the main path?

Tags: diablo-iii

In some dungeons, monsters will enter the main path by climbing up or down walls, jumping off cliffs, and so on, to enter the main path where the player is.

Some of them can be killed while they're still not on a path where the player can walk:

[image]

What happens to any items those monsters might drop, when I kill them while they're still off the main path? Do the items simply disappear (meaning I should avoid killing them until they fully arrive)?

Answer (score 6):

You do not lose the items; instead, **they appear on the closest accessible location** from where the monster is. So in your case, they will drop on the path right next to the monster. It will include the "drop" animation, so they will appear as if dropped from mid-air.

I've seen it happen a lot with flying creatures that were even further away from an accessible location than in your above screenshot, and I got their loot just fine. Fire away!